# How to combine two lists with each other?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am going to create an app in xamarin. This app will have profiles and a blog for each profile. I was thinking of doing it with listview (profiles is one list and blog another list). How can I attach two lists to each other? So when I click on a profile only their blogs will show.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You really need to explain this better.  Use pictures if it helps.  I think what you're asking is "If I click on an Item in List A on PageA, I want to navigate to PageB with List B that is filtered based on the item selected in List A?" or something like that.

Comment: Yes correct Jason. for example, I have one List A and one List B

List A is a list that will be displayed at the front page. When you click on an item in List A a new page will pop up which is showing List B.
So on each item click in List A a new page with List B will show up.

List B should be independent on List A. So List B will be specefic item depends on which List A is clicked/tapped (like a forum, when a user add a topic you can see that that topic is written byt that user)

Hope this clears it more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your first page

```
<ListView ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ... />

protected void OnItemSelect(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.SelectedItem != null) {
    // replace MyType with the appropriate type for your code
    MyType item = (MyType)args.selectedItem;
    // pass the selected item to Page2
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(item));
  }  
}
```

in Page2's constructor

```
MyType SelectedItem;

public Page2(MyType item) {
  SelectedItem = item;

  // now you can use this value to filter/etc the values
  // to populate the 2nd ListView
}
```